# What to do when accept() fails with not EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK (non-blocking IO)?

Tags: linux, sockets, posix, nonblocking

I'm writing a server program in C++. I use nonblocking POSIX socket with poll(). When the server socket is readable, my code starts to accept() the connections. When accept() fails with EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK the execution returns to poll().

On examples I saw on the Internet, if accept() fails with not EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, they terminate the server. I'm wondering if I should really do this. When accept() fails probably the client did something undefined; is this a reason to terminate my server program?

To summarize, my question is, how should I handle that when accept() fails with no EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the list of errors that can cause `accept()` to fail (In the man page). Most are recoverable; so maybe check the ones you care about and deal with whatever issue is causing that particular error.

Comment: I don't understand.   Is that not expected behaviour with a non-blocking listener??

Comment: @Shawn: Thank you.

Comment: @MartinJames: No. I need to figure out how to handle this in the code.

Comment: `accept(2)` can also fail with `ECONNABORTED`, and that doesn't sound like a reason to terminate the server, but to return to `poll()`. 
But when you're writing demo code, the safe thing to do is to bail out on any error you don't know about or don't care to handle.